# What is the chance of England scoring less than three penalties in the shootout?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I came across this problem during our maths class at the university. I am having trouble formulating this problem (wondering if my approach is correct). Am I supposed to use Binomial distribution? I am unable to find the system anywhere.

Suppose that penalty conversion probability for the players of Italy and England are as follows:

Probability of player scoring a penalty

[image]

What is the chance of England scoring less than three penalties in the
shootout?

What is the chance of Italy scoring three or more penalties?

I just need a hint about the first question (England), and that'd be enough, I believe, for me to be able to solve this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The only way I could think of is brute force, calculate all fail,  calculate the 5 different versions of 4 fails 1 success then calculate the 10 different ways of 2 successes 3 failures and adding them together since it is disjoint.  On the plus side, since the probabilities on Italy and England are the same, once you've done one of them you get the other as they are complement events

Comment: Hey Alan, yeah, I did consider that but felt that there must be a more efficient solution. Although, I don't think that's the case. I think I'll settle with that and probably try formulating it in Excel or R, though it sounds tedious as I was anyways more interested in the approach.

Thank you!